# Can an O(a+b+n) algorithm considered as an O(a(b+n)) algorithm if a>=1?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I think O(a+b+n) is always faster than O(a(b+n)) when a>=1, so an O(a+b+n) algorithm is also an O(a+(b+n)) algorithm. Is this correct? (Assume b and n is always greater or equal than 1)

Comment: Why should they be equal? I see no reason to suppose that they are. To be clear, they aren't equal, and O(a + b + n) is less than O(ab + an).

Comment: they are not equal. otherwise you can write everything as equal to O(n!^n) or something strange like this

Comment: For a basic sanity check, O(n) = O(n + n), so if that was equal to O(n * n) then O(n) would be the same as O(n^2).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I know there are not equal. But my point is can an O(a+b+n) algorithm also be considered as O(a(b+n)) algorithm because a+b+n < (a(b+n))?

Comment: Yes, because O(a) is less than O(ab), b is less than O(ab), and n is less than O(an).

Comment: Are `a` and `b` supposed to be constants?

Comment: O(a + b + n)  <= O(a + a(b+n)) = O(a(1 + b +n)) ~ O(a(b+n)) + O(a) = O(a(b+n)), if a,b,n >=1